# How to git merge squash in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit, squash

Sometimes I need to merge squash from Eclipse. I know I can do it in command line, but it will be really useful to have graphic option integrated in Eclipse. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start an **[interactive rebase in EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Interactive_Rebase)**, and select squash for the commits you want squashed.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/0b/Egit-3.2-InteractiveRebaseView.png]

---

Note: for squashing the last few commits, historically the other way was a soft reset (see [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/441231/))

> - select in history the first commit which I don't want to squash
> - right-click and say "`Team->Reset->Soft`"
> - right-click and say "`Commit`". This commit will contain all the changes of the last m commits together

Answer (score 2):

Just open the context menu on your project and choose *Team* > *Merge...*. In the resulting dialog select the option "Squash" and the branch to merge.

Also see VonC's answer for other options.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it on Windows platform, it seems my plugin version does not have this option because I'm using a version for Solaris.

Comment: I think this has been in EGit since 2.1, which is very old. So upgrading will get you lots of new features and bugfixes besides this :).