# How to squash commits using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, squash

I always use command prompt to squash  multiple commits, and i was wondering how i can do it using eclipse!

I have looked for this answer , and i have not found something useful yet.

Comment: Are you using the eGit plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git merge squash in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077750/how-to-git-merge-squash-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 5):

You cant do it today.

There is an open ticket for that:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316521

> Bug 316521 - Need ability to "squash" commits

---

## Workaround:

- Open `History` tab select all commits you want to squash.
- Then right-click the selected commits and from the context menu select `Modify | Squash`.

Comment: Not sure why you say it can't be done, but then describe how it can be done?

Comment: he asked to fo it from eclipse, not from cli

Comment: Isn't the "Workaround" describing it from Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse squash was disabled

Comment: Works perfectly in eclipse as described: history / select commits / modify / squask. Nothing is disabled here. Workaround is the solution.
The mentioned ticked has therefore been closed as fixed before this question was even asked.